# Site statistics: Effectivity of the advice to edit a question which is closed as "unclear what you're asking"

Tags: discussion, statistics

When a question is closed as "unclear what you're asking", it gets
attached the following message:

> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to
>   highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s
>   hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://mathoverflow.net/help/how-to-ask) page
>   for help clarifying this question. If this question can be reworded
>   to fit the rules in the [help center](https://mathoverflow.net/help/closed-questions), please edit the question.

According to [this statistics](https://mathoverflow.net/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=last90days), during the last 90 days following
this advice was successful precisely zero times -- i.e. no question
on MathOverflow which was closed as "unclear what you're asking" has
been edited and then reopened.

A total of 141 questions were closed as "unclear what you're asking"
during this time, of which 41 were edited without being reopened
and 5 were reopened without having been edited.

Comment: It's unclear if you're asking any question.  :)

Comment: @Lucia: I thought it's clear that I'm asking *no* question :)

Comment: Do the moderators or the 10k+ users get a notification when a closed question is edited? Maybe the problem is simply that when the question is edited and clarified it is already buried "below the fold" and no one looks at it to vote for reopening.

Comment: Edits to closed questions bump them to the top of the active question list as usual.

Comment: In addition, when a closed question is edited, it is added to the [reopen votes review queue](http://mathoverflow.net/review/reopen) where 3k+ users can decide whether or not to vote to reopen. A question (usually) remains in this queue until it is either reopened or 3 users have chosen "leave closed".

Comment: There is a vote to close as "unclear". Is this vote ironically cast, or is it for real?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: yes.

Comment: @Andrej: Your comment is not constructive! ;-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: yes.

Comment: @Andrej: I'm sorry, we were looking for the answer "Well, it's not not constructive, but that doesn't mean it's constructive either.", but thanks for playing! :-P

Comment: @Stefan Kohl: Which conclusion do you draw out of the data you present?

Comment: @Helene Sigloch: I just found it worth pointing out that so few questions closed as "unclear what you're asking" are reopened after a clarifying edit. -- I'm not sure whether there is anything one should do about this, and if yes, what.

Comment: Often this seems to mean:  "this question does not show the sophistication expected of a research-level mathematician".  If so, it's no surprise that edits for clarity are unsuccessful.